# Django duplicate existing record in database

Tags: django

I'm trying to duplicate an existing record in a PostgreSQL DB, it seems to be duplicating by increments of 2 each time I hit the duplicate button. If there's 1 record in the database, once the button is hit it will create records 2 and 3.

**Model**

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    draft = models.BooleanField()
    outage_name = models.ForeignKey(Outage, related_name='+')
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = False)
    culture_title = models.ForeignKey(Culture, related_name='+')
    work_completed = models.TextField()
    work_planned = models.TextField()
    radiation_info = models.TextField()
    action_item = models.TextField()
    lesson_learned = models.TextField()
```

**View**

```
def turnover_copy(request, id):
    obj = Detail.objects.get(pk=id)
    obj.pk = None
    obj.draft = True
    if obj.draft:
        user = request.user.id
        obj.user_id = user
        obj.work_planned = 'My Work Planned.'
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponse('Created')
    else:
    return HttpResponse('Unable to duplicate template.')
```

EDIT: I had the def inside a for loop in the template, so it kept creating duplicates!

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't called twice for some reason? Some print statements might help you assert that.

Comment: I had a template with the def inside a for loop, DOH! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: good to hear, sometimes it is the easy things :). I've created an answer out of the comment so that the question can be archived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the code isn't called twice for some reason? Some print statements might help you assert that.